# Validate onchange input fields jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There is a scenario where we have a dropdown to choose from values and also `other` option to specify value in a text input field.

Whenever, `other` option is chosen, a text field is displayed and then I want it to be validated.

`select` is:

```
<select class="form-control" name="amount_sch" id="amount_sch">
    <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="othr_amt">Other, Please Specify</option>
</select>
```

`input` is:

```
<input type="text" id="amount_sch_other" name="amount_sch_other"
 class="form-control no-extras" placeholder="Enter Amount" 
 style="display:none;"/>
```

JQuery to show/hide:

```
$("#amount_sch").change(function() { 
  if ( $(this).val() == "othr_amt") {
    $("#amount_sch_other").show();  
  }
  else{
    $("#amount_sch_other").hide();  
  }
});
```

`rules` option within `.validate()`...

```
amount_sch : {
    required : true,
}
```

With this, only `select` is validated, but how can I validate `text` field when it is visible?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself yet?  If so, where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin will dynamically ignore validation for any field that is hidden.  So you simply need to declare validation rules for the text box and let the plugin automatically do its thing.

```
rules: {
    amount_sch: {
        required: true,
    },
    amount_sch_other: {
        required: true,
    }
}
```

Whenever the text field shown, it will be validated; and when it's hidden, it will not be validated.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lcdexmwc/**

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery validate plugin by default ignore all **hidden** elements.

For your case even you set your field to required as Sparky mentioned. Or
simply add `ignore: []` to push the plugin to validate all hidden elements in the form.

```
$form.validate({
    ignore: [],
...
```